# How to make such a request in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is such a request:

```
public GetJobsListExcel(jobs: JobViewModel[] ): Promise<string> {
        let JobIds: number[] = [];
        jobs.forEach(x => JobIds.push(x.JobId));
        let url = `/api/job/jobs-list-excel?jobIds=${JobIds}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response =>
                response.text() as string
            );
    }
```

It generates a reference like: / api / job / jobs-list-excel? JobIds = $ 1,2,3 e.t.c
And what you need is like this: / api / job / jobs-list-excel? JobIds = $ 1? JobIds = $ 2? JobIds = $ 3

I tried on everyone, does not go out, in what direction to dig? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to pass `JobIds` to API `,` separated list of `number` as string

```
let url = `/api/job/jobs-list-excel?jobIds=${JobIds.join(',')}`
```

And the on server side do `split` JobIds string by `,`(comma)

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you need multiple `JobIds` query strings as you have asked in your question

```
let url = `/api/job/jobs-list-excel?JobIds=${JobIds.join('&JobIds=')}` 
// => "/api/job/jobs-list-excel?JobIds=1&JobIds=2&JobIds=3&JobIds=4"
```